# What does this sed command do in this script?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I am new to shell scripting, and I don't understand what this `sed` command does. Can you help with some explanation?

```
cat $fRostroTmp | sed "s/ *|/;/g" >> $fRostroCsv
rm -f $fRostroTmp
```

Comment: all of the code, please

Comment: no, i just dont't understand what sed "s/ *|/;/g" does. There are many characters and I dont get it

Comment: the sed expression searches for zero or more spaces followed by |, replaces with a ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, you ask specifically about the `sed` expression `s/ *|/;/g`.

This is a substitution command (`s`) which substitutes whatever the regular expression  `*|` matches with the single character `;`.

The expression  `*|` matches zero or more spaces followed by a `|` character.  So wherever this occurs in the input, it will be replaced by `;`.

The `g` at the end of the expression causes `sed` to apply the substitution to all non-overlapping matches on each line, not just the first match.  This means that a line saying

```
1 2 3 | 3 4 5 | 5 6 6
```

or

```
1 2 3| 3 4 5     | 5 6 6
```

would be transformed into

```
1 2 3; 3 4 5; 5 6 6
```